# Date/Timestamp WITH[OUT] TIME ZONE

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

Is the `WITH TIME ZONE` a postgres-only thing? I'm used to seeing the following three items usually in databases:

- Date (used as something like '4th of July')
- Time (the local news is on at 5:00pm)
- Datetime (A movie comes out at midnight, Feb 17)
- Timestamp (a specific moment in time -- such as when I asked this question)

`Datetime` is never with a time zone, `Timestamp` is with a time zone, and `Time` is (usually?) not with a time zone. What then is the use of the `WITH[OUT] TIME ZONE` in Postgres, as I've never really seen that in any other databases -- is that historical baggage or something else?

I suppose postgres just equates the data types of:

- `Timestamp` = `timestamp WITH TIME ZONE`
- `Datetime` = `timestamp WITHOUT TIME ZONE`

Is that correct?

Comment: A timestamp **is** a "date time" (=date _and_ time). Something like "4th of July" is a `date`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name right. I suppose a easier-to-follow version would be how Mysql handles date/time/datetime: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry that was a mistake I forgot to add in the `datetime` type.

Comment: SQL Server has datetimeoffset

Comment: Well, there is no data type `datetime` in Postgres (or standard SQL). There is `timestamp` **without** time zone which probably is, what you think a "datetime" is.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name oh I see -- so how postgres does it is the standard/ansi way, and something like mysql with the additional `datetime` type is less standard and just a conveneince?

Comment: Yes, the types `timestamp with time zone` and `timestamp without time zone` are defined in the SQL standard (and at least Postgres, DB2 and Firebird have the same). So it's not "a Postgres thing". But I don't understand what difference you see between a `datetime` and a  `timestamp without time zone`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no difference, I was just curious until I read your comments thread, so that solves it. I didn't realize those were exactly the same 'data type' if you want to call it that